# ASP.NET session variables lost in shared hosting environment

Tags: asp.net, hosting, shared, application-shutdown

I'm using ASP.NET 4.8. My webapp uses standard session state variables.  On my local machine, everything is fine.  On GoDaddy the site is in a shared hosting environment.

When hosted, the Application_End event is being triggered on most requests; I can see that in my logs.  All the error says is "shutdown initiated by hosting environment".

I've tried many things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Turn on sql based sessions. Thus a server farm can be used since now session is not ram based but database based.

Comment: After researching this, it appears that you can't just "turn it on".  It requires a SQL database and tables, and special session management code.  Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you require to setup and add the sql tables,  but zero code changes are required.  So yes you setup and create the session tables,  and yes you have session settings in web.config, but no code is to be changed.  Rare cases are objects that don't support serialization such as a datarow, but in general no code changes are required.  I recommend sql sessions for all production sites and I find stunning improvements in reliability. So yes in effect you turn this on, and it's no more effort than say setting up a connection to some database.  So this is configuration and not a code change

Answer (score 0):

Most shared hosting provider doesn't permit you to use session on your code as it will impact to server performance. As an alternative, you can use Cookie or Asp.net session state.

Comment: Sorry, but can you be more specific?  I'm using the default "InProc" mode in the ASP.Net 4.8 "framework"..  What is the difference between that and "Cookie" mode?  What do you mean by "Asp.net session state"? Can I use ViewState?  Thanks.

Comment: Viewstate is per web page,  not per user and thus Viewstate can't be used to pass values between pages. Viewstate is based on local browsers storage and travels up to server on each post back (which slows things down and thus Viewstate needs to be kept small). In proc memory session is supported by near all web hosting   the exception is of course cloud computing and server farms since your site not limited to one server and thus memory can't transfer between servers running your site.  Once again the solution is sql based session management